# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 provider stops working after installing MS Office 2016

Tags: .net, oledb

I have an old .NET application that connects to MS Access Database with a connection string like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="QuickNote.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=..\..\MyBook.accdb;Mode=ReadWrite"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

to run it on Windows 10 I install `accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.exe` or `accessruntime_4288-1001_x86_en-us.exe`.

It probably sounds a bit strange, but when I install MS Office 2016 or higher the application stops working, because it can't connect to DB.

What was changed in MS Access?

Where can I see available .NET providers?

Answer (score 1):

It is because MS Office 2016 installs 64 bit driver, but I previously used 32 bit.